# How do you display images in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

How do you render images (.bmp and .jpeg) using OpenGL ? 
I've come across some tutorials, but they were for C# not C/C++.
The reason I want to render images, is because I want to draw a spaceship(for a game). I could  use a OpenGL primitive, but it doesn't really look that great. The other option is to draw the spaceship using co-ordinates, but that would take ages, and wouldnt look as good.

running the following snippet always returns failed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glfw.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  GLFWimage image;
  if(glfwReadImage("ship.tga", &image, GLFW_ORIGIN_UL_BIT)!=GL_TRUE);
  cout << "FAILED";
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?
Poorly written code. Sorry about that. Works now

Comment: Look for NeHe tutorials, they explain all the basics with code in dozens of languages, C++ included.

Comment: The "ship.tga" file is in the same directory as the .exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By texturing a Quad (or better yet, two Triangles).

Unless you really need `.bmp` or `.jpeg`, I would suggest that you use `.tga` (Targa) images as they are more commonly used and support alpha channel.

Some C++ resources:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/loading_compressed_and_uncompressed_tgas/22001/

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/

http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html (a great little image library for OpenGL. Supports bmp, jpg, png, tga, etc.)

Comment: I dont 'really need' them. The reason I suggested those, was because it's easy to obtain/create them. How do I create a `.tga` file ?

Comment: Nevermind. I found a site online that converts images to `.tga`
http://www.online-utility.org/image_converter.jsp

Comment: @viraj I forgot to mention that in my post. I prefer to use Paint.net when working on .tga files. It saves both compressed and uncompressed, 24/32-bit.

Comment: OMG, it's 2020 an I'm still having to go through this "you're missing a library" and then another library and then another library and then another library and then another library. Oh well, maybe next year.

Answer (score 2):

Render a textured quad or two triangles that form a rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

Quake-like games are rendering humans like cubes with different textures on it's side. You can do that as well. Enable alpha blending and make sure the transparent texture data is really transparent.